# Why this function doesn't actualize user value?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cubit

I am writting this flutter app using bloc/cubit architecture.
I want to change user value but the function seems not working.

The print result I want is: 1-old user, 2-new user

Can you help me to understand why?

Here is my code

**user favourite list**

```
class FavouritesSrcreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FavouritesSrcreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LayoutCubit, LayoutStates>(builder: (context, state) {
      var cubit = LayoutCubit.get(context);
      return Scaffold(
          body: ListView.separated(
                  ...
                    return ListTile(
                       ...
                        onTap: () {
                          print('1 ' + cubit.user.name);
                          cubit.getUserDataById(
                            cubit.users[index].uid,
                          );
                          print('2 ' + cubit.user.name);
                          cubit.changeIsFavourite();
                        });
                  },
                ));
    });
  }
}
```

**cubit**

```
...
  void getUserDataById(String id) {
    emit(LayoutGetUserLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).get().then((value) {
      user = UserData.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value.data())));
      emit(LayoutGetOtherUserSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
      emit(LayoutGetOtherUserErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
...
```

Comment: could you explain more  . what do you want to do ?

Comment: Can you please show the output window as well. It's not very explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call following method (FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(id).get()) in main thread using await and convert getUserDataById to future and call this method with await.